# Simplify $x^TA(AA^T+I)^{-1}A^Tx$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

I need to simplify the term
$$x^TA(AA^T+I)^{-1}A^Tx$$

where $A$ is $N\times n$ matrix and $x$ is a $N\times 1$ vector.

I have some information of $x^Tx$. Could anyone know how to simplify the term as close as possible to $x^Tx$ ?

Comment: Knowing $x^Tx$ is not enough information to calculate $x^TMx$ for a fixed matrix $M$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom it's true. However I have other terms in the form $x^Tf(A)x$ that should be simplified if I am able to simplify the term in the question.

Comment: @ThomasPastor Please state *everything* that you already know about $A$ and $x$ above because as it stands you cannot do anything about the above expression.

Comment: It seems like you're thinking "if only I could simply this, I would be able to reach my goal". Most likely the best way to reach your goal is not simplifying this expression, if it is even possible.
Is this part of a bigger problem? What are you trying to get at?

Comment: The matrix dimensions are not compatible: $$\eqalign{A&\in{\mathbb R}^{N\times n}\cr(AA^T)^{-1}&\in{\mathbb R}^{N\times N}\cr}$$so $A(AA^T)^{-1}$ can only exist when $(n=N)$.